# Groovy + Antbuilder: How to use Grape to with taskdef?

Tags: groovy, ant, classloader, groovy-grape, taskdef

This is related to .  I'm trying to dynamically add the maven-ant-tasks jars with Grape, simulating this:

```
  <taskdef uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
           resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
           classpathref="ant.classpath" />
```

I've tried to use Grape.grab() to make maven-ant-tasks available to AntBuilder like this:

```
import groovy.grape.Grape

println "grab..."
Grape.grab(group:'ant', module:'ant', version:'1.7.0', classLoader:this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)
Grape.grab(group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-ant-tasks', version: '2.0.9')

println "ant taskdef..."
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.taskdef (resource: "org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" )
```

but that doesn't work because Grape adds the modules to a different ClassLoader from the one that ANT engine is using.  So, I took the advice from [this AntBuilder classpath question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641116/groovy-with-grape-and-antbuilder-classloader-problem) and made Grape use the root ClassLoader:

```
import groovy.grape.Grape

println "grab..."
Grape.grab(group:'ant', module:'ant', version:'1.7.0', classLoader:this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)
Grape.grab(group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-ant-tasks', version: '2.0.9', classLoader: this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)

println "ant taskdef..."
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.taskdef (resource: "org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" )
```

Now it throws a LinkageError:

```
Caught: : java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelper2$RootHandler, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/Locator used in the signature
 at test.mavenanttasks.run(mavenanttasks.groovy:11)
```

Any hints on getting this to work?  Or, is the whole thing a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+Libraries+with+AntBuilder

First, put maven-ant-tasks in the root classloader with:

```
@Grapes([
@Grab(group = 'org.apache.maven', module = 'maven-ant-tasks', version = '2.1.3'),
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
])
```

Alternatively, for older versions of Groovy:

```
Grape.grab(group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-ant-tasks', version: '2.1.3', classLoader: this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)
```

The Maven ANT tasks are an 'AntLib', and they can be loaded like this:

```
import groovy.xml.NamespaceBuilder
def ant = new AntBuilder()
def mvn = NamespaceBuilder.newInstance(ant, 'antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant')
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create ant path(classpath) using  java.net.URLClassLoader or it's subclass 
eg:

```
<!-- language: groovy -->
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.jacoco', module='org.jacoco.ant', version= '0.7.4.201502262128'),
    @Grab(group='org.jacoco', module='org.jacoco.core', version= '0.7.4.201502262128'),
    @Grab('org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.4.201502262128'),   
])
class Tool {
    def dump(args){
        println "do dump...:$args"
        println "DumpTask:"+org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask.classLoader;
        def ant = new AntBuilder();
        def path1 = ant.path{
            org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask.classLoader.getURLs().each {
                ant.pathelement(location:it.getFile())
            }
        } 
        println "path11:$path1";

    // classname way
    //  ant.taskdef(name:"dump",classname:"org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask",classpath:path1);
    //  ant.dump(args);

        //namespace way
        ant.taskdef(uri:'antlib:org.jacoco.ant',resource:'org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml',classpath:path1);
        def jacoco=groovy.xml.NamespaceBuilder.newInstance(ant, 'antlib:org.jacoco.ant')
        jacoco.dump(args);
    }
}
```